# The server does not support SSL connections

Tags: javascript, postgresql, docker, docker-compose

I have two docker containers, one for a postgres image on Docker hub and one for my express server.

```yaml
services:
  database:
    image: postgres:latest
    environment:
      - POSTGRES_USER=postgres
      - POSTGRES_PASSWORD=admin123
      - POSTGRES_DB=ticketsellermadrid_dev
      - PGSSLMODE=disable
      - PGREQUIRESSL=0
  app:
    image: ticket-seller-back:1.0.0
    ports:
      - "8080:8080"
    env_file:
      - .env.development
```

And a NodeJS app with express and Sequelize with this configuration:

```js
const sequelize = new Sequelize({
    username: process.env.DB_OWNER,
    password: process.env.DB_PASSWORD,
    host: process.env.DB_HOST,
    port: parseInt(process.env.DB_PORT!),
    database: process.env.DB_NAME,
    dialect: "postgres",
});
```

Why I'm getting the error `The server does not support SSL connections` if my server doesn't have any SSL connection configuration?

What I am missing?

Thank you!

Comment: Where is the error message coming from?

Comment: sequelize ```ticket-seller-madrid-back-database-1  | 2023-07-16 16:14:35.334 UTC [1] LOG:  database system is ready to accept connections
ticket-seller-madrid-back-app-1       | ConnectionError [SequelizeConnectionError]: The server does not support SSL connections```

Comment: PGSSLMODE and PGREQUIRESSL are client variables.  They don't do anything when specified on the server. (unless the server is also a client)

Comment: You dont have ANY idea of what is happening right? PGSSLMODE and PGREQUIRESSL are client variables ok, and? If I remove them I resolve the problem? NO

Answer (score 0):

You can either update the database url by adding ?sslmode=disable
for example:

```
DATABASE_URL: postgres://user:password@db:5432/dbname?sslmode=disable
```

or modify the configuration in your code to disable SSL:

```js
Pool({
  connectionString: process.env.DATABASE_URL,
  ssl: false,
});
```